# Task Bar is not working Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I am having problem with my Windows 10 Taskbar. I can't click on tray icons nor i can search in the search box. Even if i press window key from keyboard nothing pops up . I don't know why it's happening ! I have restarted my laptop several times but that's not the problem.

I am having hard times even in restarting/switching my laptop.What i do now is pressing `CTRL+L` and from there i shut my laptop, i can't do it directly from start menu as it is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 taskbar not working](http://superuser.com/questions/970803/windows-10-taskbar-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a virus to me. Could you download [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) and run it.

There is however a way to test a workaround. Could you press CTRL+ALT+DEL, start taskmanager, search the task Explorer.exe, kill it, press File and select Run new task. Please fill in explorer.exe in this screen and press enter. Now try to click on your taskbar.